# Moving to OpenLayers from Google maps

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm looking for some help on comparative `OpenLayer` functions for the following Google maps functions, can someone please let me know what these would be?

I'm currently using

1. For getting distance, using the distance matrix API:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix

2. For getting latitude and longitude of the current address:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address

Kindly check the attachment which are using for getting latitude, longitude and distance matrix.

Function names:

1. `function getLatLng($add)`
2. `function getRoadDistance($from, $to)`

--

Answer (score 1):

things are a little bit more complicated in OL than they are with the google-api

1. Routing: if you have a small road network you can consider creating a Database in PostGIS and use pgrouting to get routing functions, you can find more on it [here](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/doc/index.html)

Or if you want to use it on a bigger scale there some APIs that do it for you, for example yourNavigator, you'll have to make a get request with your coordinates like this

```
http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=geojson&flat=startLatitude&flon=startLongitude&tlat=destLatitude&tlon=destinationLongitude
```

there is also the OSRM for the same purpose.

2. to get the longitude and latitude based on an address you can use the [geocoder](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3-geocoder) for Openlayers 3

that's what I could think of right now, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hicham